Warning: An unhandled error was caught from submitForm() TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object at formik.esm.js:784:31
Issue facing :
I cannot submit the form to the dev/production server.
But in the local code, it is working fine for me.
Warning: An unhandled error was caught from submitForm() TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object
at formik.esm.js:784:31
Version
"formik": "2.4.6",
"yup": "0.28.5"


It is not possible to provide a solution without looking at the actual code. Please provide a minimum, reproducible example (refer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
